# MICROS 3700 ResPosApiWeb API client configuration record

Tags: c#, point-of-sale

We are working on integration with Micros POS 3700 (v. 4.8).

When we send any request to its web interface, we got the following error:
Server was unable to process request. --> The type initializer for &quot;ResPosApiWeb.ResPosApiWebService&quot; threw an exception. --> The API client configuration record could not be found.

We did everything according to official documentation - created employee and employee class, registered new device node, device and workstation. Control panel displays our node and it is marked green.

We spent a lot of time trying to figure out what is wrong and we tried many ways of fixing it, but nothing worked. There is no information about this error in documentation and we were not able to find anything about it in the Internet. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just got solved .......

after following the guide setups do the following steps.

Add A New device as DiskFile with same Network Node.

Set this as printer in UserWorkstations in following priners

1. Customer Receipt printer
2. Guest Check Printer
3. CA Voucher Printer
4. Journal Printer.

Answer (score 1):

For mine it was a stuck check. A stuck check from 5 days prior that RESDBS didnt know how to handle, and when POSAPI asked for an update on the check it was spitting a SQL error. Spent 3 hours double checking IIS, configurator and random files for a freaking stuck check.

Answer (score 0):

Another item to consider is to ensure the 3700 system is in DEMO mode (Or properly licensed) -- proper licensing is required for this feature and the web-service will fail to respond if not properly licensed.  The 3700d Log shows the following...

*** ERROR *** 3700 POS System is not properly licensed. | 
Fri Oct 12 15:13:25 2012 | SERVER           | POSAPI          |        0 | Failed to Create or Initialize ResDbs Interface, HRESULT = c701045f |

Fri Oct 12 15:13:25 2012 | SERVER           | POSAPI          |        0 | [0xC701045F] The API client configuration record could not be found. |

Assuming you are ***NOT*** working on a production system and you wish to place the system into DEMO mode, do the following;

**Start -> Programs -> Micros Applications -> Utilities -> License Manager**

Ensure the [ ] Demo check-box is checked.  (also each section can be separately enabled into demo mode, if you are developing on a live system (not recommended))

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I just resolved this issue another way...  I tried all the solutions above with no success, but ultimately fixed it by replacing the ResPosApiWeb.asmx with a copy from a functioning environment.
I have no idea how it got corrupted, but the one in there was 8 years old.